# Java, How to collect filtered out values in Spark

Tags: java, filter, apache-spark

My Input is a collection of strings, Say :

```
Chicago
Washington
Seattle
San Francisco
Chicago
Newyork
Dallas
```

I have the below code which filters out certain values:

```
        List<String> filteredValues =  new ArrayList<String>();
        JavaRDD<String> filteredOutput = inputText.filter(line -> {

                if(line.toLowerCase().contains("chicago")) {
                    filteredValues.add(line);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;

        });
       System.out.println("Filtered values are" + filteredValues.toString());
    }
}
```

I expected "filteredValues" list to contain `[Chicago, Chicago].`

But its empty. Can someone help me out.

Comment: filteredOutput.collect

Comment: yeah i did that. prior. and its contents were all the values excluding "chicago". so it worked. but still the list is empty

Comment: @Vikram Read this bit about [understanding closures](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka) in Spark. There is a functional disconnect in what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is more functional, so updating a variable won't work.* You should use the output from the `filter` and call `collect`.

Also, you need to return true if you want to keep an item. It appears you've got this backwards.

*closed over variables are COPIED to each worker. So the updates are only the worker local copy.

Comment: Thank you Justin. But As per your suggestion, if i call collect(), all that what I get is [Washington,Seattle,San Francisco,Newyork, Dallas] which I m aware of. How do I get the values that were filtered out during this process? Lets say I need a list of values that were filtered out [Chicago, Chicago].

Comment: Updated my answer. Your filter is backwards

Comment: Sorry justin.. But my requirement is such that i want to seperate out filtered ones and non-filtered ones, and save both of them. One in rdd form and other as a list